# Independence and conditionals

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given random variables $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ where it is known that $A$ and $B$ are independent (i.e. $P(A,B)=P(A)P(B)$) is the following manipulation correct?

$$P(A,B|C,D)=\frac{P(A,B,C,D)}{P(C,D)}=\frac{P(A|B,C,D)P(B,C,D)}{P(C,D)}\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{P(A|C,D)P(B,C,D)}{P(C,D)}$$

where I dropped the $B$ from the conditioning list of the first numerator term under the thought that since $A$ and $B$ are independent, conditioning on $B$ won't effect $A$. I know this is true for the two variable case $P(A|B)=P(A)$, but can't prove it when those other conditioning variables exist.

Continuing on we have:

$$\frac{P(A|C,D)P(B,C,D)}{P(C,D)}=\frac{P(A|C,D)P(B|C,D)P(C,D)}{P(C,D)}=P(A|C,D)P(B|C,D)$$

showing conditional independence.

Comment: This is incorrect. $A$ and $B$ can be independent and yet be conditionally dependent given $C,D$. For instance, let $A$ and $B$ be independent $\textrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, and $C := A \oplus B,$ where $\oplus$ is the XOR operation. By construction, $A$ is independent of $B$, but $A = B \oplus C,$ and thus $P(A= 0| B= 0, C = 0) \neq P(A = 0|C = 0).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Simplifying to three events, $A,B,E$.  Knowing that $A\perp B$, gives no assurance that $A\perp B\mid E$.   (That is: Knowing $A$ and $B$ are independent, does not imply that $A$ and $B$ will be conditionally independent given $E$).

IE: $\mathsf P(A,B)=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B)$ does *not* mean $\mathsf P(A,B\mid E)=\mathsf P(A\mid E)~\mathsf P(B\mid E)$.

---

Clasic counter example: toss two coins.  Let $A$ be the event that the first coin shows heads, $B$ the event that the second does, and $E$ the event that both coins show the same face.   Then $A$ and $B$ are independent events, but they are *not* conditionally independent when given that *they show the same face*.